# Call postRemove not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4, symfony-eventdispatcher

I have a problem with my project :

`Not called :`

```
public function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
{
    $test = 1;
    $test1 = 2;
}
```

`Called :`

```
public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
{
    $test = 1;
    $test1 = 2;
}
```

Strange that postRemove is not called. I confirm that the entity is deleted from database. Please give an idea.

Comment: Place die() to make sure it's not being called. Also don't forget to register listener and add subscribed events function.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        'postPersist',
        'postUpdate',
        'postRemove' // !!! 
    );
}

public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    dump('Update');
}

public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    dump('Persist');
}


public function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    dump('Remove');
}
```